# parenthesis ,or without parenthesis?

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following function:

$$f(x)=\sin2x;-\pi\leq x<-\frac{\pi}{2}$$

if i consider 2 within parenthesis $\sin[2(-\pi)]$, it is equal to $0$.

if i do not consider 2 within parenthesis $\sin2(-\pi)$, it is equal to $-2.856642116$.

Why does the result vary?

Which one will I consider for my given exercise? Parenthesis ,or without parenthesis?

Comment: because without that parenthesis, compiling program probably read it as $\sin(2)\times(-\pi)$, look here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%282%29%C3%97%28%E2%88%92%CF%80%29

Comment: Make it unambiguous, you mean $\sin(2 x)$, so write that in code.

Comment: @DannyCheuk Thank you very much. I got my answer. So i need to consider $2$ within parenthesis for my exercise. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your exercise, it is certainly $\sin (2x)$. Like what the commenter mentioned above, your calculator/computer interprets the one without parentheses as $(\sin (2)) \cdot (\pi)$. But if this is what is wanted from you, it should've been written $x \sin 2$ instead, to avoid ambiguity.